# Kendo Grid Export to Excel "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I have used entity framework, and  I am trying to export to excel. It keeps telling me that my input string is incorrect. I have them all converted to string, and I can not figure out which one it doesn't like. Could it be the header rows? and if so, how do I fix this?

```
 private BaselineDataEntities db = new BaselineDataEntities();
    public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        //Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
        IEnumerable products = db.ProductQualityFileFulls.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;

        //Create new Excel workbook
        var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        //Create new Excel sheet
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();


       // //Create a header row
        var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

       //// Set the column names in the header row
        headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Recent Update Status");
        headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Marketing Rep");
        headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Customer Name");
        headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Opt-In Status");
        headerRow.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("Store ID");
        headerRow.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Dealer");
        headerRow.CreateCell(6).SetCellValue("DBA Name");
        headerRow.CreateCell(7).SetCellValue("Class");
        headerRow.CreateCell(8).SetCellValue("Act Code Desc");
        headerRow.CreateCell(9).SetCellValue("Jobber");
        headerRow.CreateCell(10).SetCellValue("Jobber Name");
        headerRow.CreateCell(11).SetCellValue("SubJobber");
        headerRow.CreateCell(12).SetCellValue("Company Op Desc");
        headerRow.CreateCell(13).SetCellValue("Longitude");
        headerRow.CreateCell(14).SetCellValue("Latitude");
        headerRow.CreateCell(15).SetCellValue("Local Address");
        headerRow.CreateCell(16).SetCellValue("Local Address 2");
        headerRow.CreateCell(17).SetCellValue("Local City");
        headerRow.CreateCell(18).SetCellValue("Local County");
        headerRow.CreateCell(19).SetCellValue("Local State");
        headerRow.CreateCell(20).SetCellValue("Local Postal");
        headerRow.CreateCell(21).SetCellValue("Phone");
        headerRow.CreateCell(22).SetCellValue("Establish Date");
        headerRow.CreateCell(23).SetCellValue("Establish ID"); 

       //// (Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
       // sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);

        int rowNumber = 1;

        //Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
        foreach (ProductQualityFileFull product in products)
        {
            //Create a new row
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);

            //Set values for the cells
            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(product.RecUpdtStatus.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(product.mktRep.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(product.CustName.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(product.OptInd.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(product.StoreId.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(product.dealerNo.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(6).SetCellValue(product.DBAName.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(7).SetCellValue(product.Class.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(8).SetCellValue(product.ActCodedesc.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(9).SetCellValue(product.Jobber.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(10).SetCellValue(product.JobberName.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(11).SetCellValue(product.SubJobber.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(12).SetCellValue(product.CompanyOpDesc.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(13).SetCellValue(product.Longitude.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(14).SetCellValue(product.Latitude.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(15).SetCellValue(product.LocAddress.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(16).SetCellValue(product.LocAddress2.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(17).SetCellValue(product.LocCity.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(18).SetCellValue(product.LocCounty.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(19).SetCellValue(product.LocState.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(20).SetCellValue(product.LocPostalCode.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(21).SetCellValue(product.Phone.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(22).SetCellValue(product.establish_date_time.ToString());
            row.CreateCell(23).SetCellValue(product.establish_id.ToString());
        }

       // Write the workbook to a memory stream
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.Write(output);

        //eturn the result to the end user

        return File(output.ToArray(),   //The binary data of the XLS file
            "application/vnd.ms-excel", //MIME type of Excel files
            "GridExcelExport.xls");     //Suggested file name in the "Save as" dialog which will be displayed to the end user

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well have you tried just commenting out the content and building it up piece by piece. 
Without knowing how your data is built up it's difficult to say what your issue is and if you break point through the code you should be able to find out where the problem is (or debug statements)

As you are using npoi this little library may be of use for you:

[Excel Helper](https://github.com/JellyMaster/excelhelper)

This is a project I built which can easily take a flatten list collection and turn it into an excel file both xls and xlsx file types. It is purely just to get data and doesn't do any of the fancy graph stuff but is great for just getting data into a sheet.